# How to run Elasticsearch on Cloudfoundry

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud-foundry

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/rails-elastic-search#setting-up-elastic-search

The link above is the only information I've found about running ES on cloudfoundry and it's not working for me.   I downloaded the latest ES, updated the config/elasticsearch.yml and copied over the elastic-search-manifest.yml file.

The next step says to run,

```
vmc push --manifest=elastic-search-manifest.yml
```

but --manifest= isn't valid.

I tried running the following

```
vmc push es_index
```

But during the deploy I get this message.

[WARNING] Can't determine the Application Type.

```
1: Sinatra
2: Lift
3: WSGI
4: JavaWeb
5: Node
6: PHP
7: Erlang/OTP Rebar
8: Grails
9: Django
10: Rails
11: Spring
```

I tried selecting JavaWeb and Rais, but those don't work either.

It seems like I need to bootstrap the startup of /bin/elasticsearch somehow.

Update: I tried writing a little node.js bootstrap to start the elasticsearch process, but got a Permission Denied error.

Comment: Have you tried the vcap-dev google group? Specifically this thread may be useful: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/d/topic/vcap-dev/svuMeunzccE/discussion

Comment: It looks like you may be using an older version of vmc, as I don't see Standalone listed as a framework type (which is what the manifest specifies for ElasticSearch).  Try doing a "gem update vmc", you should be on at least 0.3.18, and then --manifest should work.

Comment: @JenniferHickey, Yes you are correct.  Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Jennifer Hickey's answer in the comments:

> It looks like you may be using an older version of vmc, as I don't see Standalone listed as a framework type (which is what the manifest specifies for ElasticSearch). Try doing a "gem update vmc", you should be on at least 0.3.18, and then --manifest should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of running your own cloudfoundry cluster, you have another choice:
ElasicSearch has been added as a service, so you don't need to add it as an application anymore. You could just provision it and bind your apps to it, just as you do with e.g. MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and the instructions on https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/rails-elastic-search/blob/master/elastic-search-manifest.yml work well for me with elasticsearch-0.19.11.

Things to try:

- save the manifest as manifest.yml - which is the default that VMC looks for, then you won't need the command line switch.
- edit the manifest and change the name to one that isn't taken (they're global for each CloudFoundry).
- check your VMC version. I'm using 0.3.18, with api.cloudfoundry.com as the target.